# Server not accepting request on port 9999

Tags: linux, sockets, amazon-ec2, phpwebsocket, phpws

I am trying to deploy my socket[phpws library] on amazon EC2 instance. For this I deployed code and run socket. I have selected port 9999 for socket handshake, but it is not working.
I tried to captured request on this server by command :

```
sudo tcpdump -i any port 9999
```

Then I hit this port, I did not received any request. I thought this is because of iptables. So I checked it by command :

```
sudo iptables -L
```

But it clearly shows allow for all requests. Here is output :

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>   target     prot opt source               destination

At this point I am clueless how to move forward. Any help is gently appreciable. Looking for response.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also open port `9999` in the AWS Security Group attached to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes, I was fighting with this silly mistake since past few hours. Thanks a ton for your help.